# Domain Masking / Cloaking?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

I don't know what the correct term is for this but I'd like to
redirect `exampleA.com` to `exampleB.com` without changing the URL in their address bar at all.

**So for example:**

- User visits: `exampleA.com` and gets redirected to `exampleB.com`
- Address Bar: Displays `exampleA.com`

Additionally all links on `exampleB.com` should be shown as `exampleA.com` in the status bar and address bar.

- Is this possible? How?
- What is the ramifications of this in terms of SEO?

Comment: sounds dangerous. and off topic.

Comment: What OS/webserver stack are you using?

Comment: @Edgar: Its not what you're thinking. :S

Comment: @Corey: Shared Hosting so Linux/Apache.

Answer (score 3):

This will hurt your SEO as you will run into duplicate content issues. If you do this you need to use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to tell Google which site is the main site you want to see listed in their search engines. It also acts like a 301 redirect so links to the secondary domain count towards its counterpart on the primary domain.